# Hibernate connection and JDBC connection difference

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, connection

There is something I don't understand :
Is Hibernate a DB manager and not only ORM?
My question: I have SpringBootApplication and use hibernate for connection to database and ORM aspect. In my mind, connection to DB is continuous.
On another hand, I want a puncual on-demand connection to an access DB, so I used simple java.sql.* library :

```
Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver").newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://myDB.mdb", login, password);
```

This works but in order to not map manually each result query to a domain object, I would like to use hibernate to do :

```
getCurrentSession()
  .createSQLQuery( "select e.id as id,e.first_name as firstName,e.password as password from xxxxxx")
                .addScalar("id",StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER )
                .addScalar("firstName",StandardBasicTypes.STRING )
                .addScalar("password",StandardBasicTypes.STRING )
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
                .list();
```

in order to have query result automatically bind to DOmain object.

BUT this is only available for hibernate library, not java.sql (or I didn't find).
SO should I have a second hibernate connection but not permanent so not configured in application.properties/hibernate.properties and so not managed by Spring (in order to have punctual connection)? In my mind, I would like to do something identical to java.sql previous example but with hibernate.

You will understand that I think I miss something about hibernate philosophy.

Thank you.